# What is the Linux equivalent of Windows critical sections?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, synchronization, posix

The Windows NT operating system has the `EnterCriticalSection` and `ExitCriticalSection` objects to allow for synchronization between threads.

What is the Linux equivalent, while using the GCC compiler?

I see references around to `__sync_synchronize` along with `__scoped_lock`

In fact I see mention of a number of atomic `__sync` functions along with a number of
`__atomic` ones.

I actually have been using `__sync_fetch_and_add` for my atomic increment
Should I be using `__atomic_add_dispatch` instead?
What's the difference?

Which ones should I be using?  Are there some constructs in C++ that I can use in both the latest version of GCC and Visual C++ 2010 that are available as I'm going to be writing some cross platform code.

I see boost has some functions available, but for various reasons I'm not allowed to use boost under windows.

Comment: I suppose you cannot use any other library either then? Qt has a nice (cross-platform) threading API.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On Linux (and other Unixen) you need to use PThreads, or Posix Threads. There is no equivalent to Critical Sections on Windows; use a Mutex instead.

EDIT: See first comment below -- apparently Posix Mutexes are the same as Win32 Critical Sections in that they are bound to a single process.

Comment: Actually, POSIX mutexes are equivalent to Win32 Critical Sections (process-bounded); Win32 Mutexes differ from Critical Sections in being cross-process.

Comment: @MSalters: Ah -- didn't know that. Must smash terminology reuse.

Comment: @MSalters, Also, Win32 Critical Sections are a lot faster than Win32 mutexes because they are implemented in user space and don't involve the overhead associated with system call. I don't know about Posix mutexes though ?

Comment: @Tanuj: You might want to benchmark that statement. Most threading overhead is usually the result of context switches, rather than locking, in any case.

Comment: it strongly depends on the contention. On a highly contended lock, context-switching to other threads will dominate. On a lighly contended lock, a context switch between user space and kernel space would dominate (which a Win32 Critical Section avoids in the uncontended case)

Comment: I did some testing, and in heavy contesting conditions by many threads, windows' critical sections are significantly faster than linux mutex

Comment: @Arsen: Wouldn't have surprised me either way. They're different beasts under the hood, to my (very limited) understanding. I know the Windows guys spent a lot of time optimizing the way locks behave.

Comment: Well linux has futexs which are in userspace and faster than mutexs. I do not know how the speed of these compare to Win32 critical sections.

Answer (score 10):

Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section

```
/* Sample C/C++, Unix/Linux */
#include <pthread.h>

/* This is the critical section object (statically allocated). */
static pthread_mutex_t cs_mutex =  PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;

void f()
{
    /* Enter the critical section -- other threads are locked out */
    pthread_mutex_lock( &cs_mutex );

    /* Do some thread-safe processing! */

    /*Leave the critical section -- other threads can now pthread_mutex_lock()  */
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &cs_mutex );
}

int main()
{
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`EnterCriticalSection` and the rest of the APIs are Win32 APIs. As far as cross-platform synchronization APIs, I don't think there are any (since you mention you can't use boost). Also, you mentioned cross-platform, does this mean different architectures too (for the gcc part i.e.).
I've seen one large implementation where there was a common set of APIs provided which were conditionally compiled to have the native APIs (like fetch_and_add on AIX) or used pthreads the Win32 APIs.
I once tried to use [posix threads on win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) but ran into a bunch of issues (but that was a very old version). Now YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing programs only for Windows platform, I think the best way is using Win32 API. Otherwise you can use Qt C++ libraries (for that purpose Qt Core is enough).

See also: [QMutex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmutex.html) and [QMutexLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html)
You can also use: [QReadWriteLock](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qreadwritelock.html)